# Не работает дефолтное отключение поведения ссылки

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

Практика для себя в yii2, столкнувшаяся с проблемой, которая возникает при добавлении товара в корзину, и не открывается модальное окно с данными (вопрос принципиально не существует). и e.preventDefault () ;, и вернуть false;) Собственно в примере будут оба варианта. Подскажите в чем может быть речь?

применял и e.preventDefault () ;, и вернуть false;

Сама ссылка в файле модели:

```
<a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/add', 'id' => $hit->id])?>"  data-id="<?= $hit->id?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
```

Код js в файле main.js:

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
let id = $(this).data('id');
$.ajax({
    url: '/cart/add',
    data: {id: id},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
return false;
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/cart/add',
            data: {id: id},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде бы использовал документ, но все ровно не вышло, а теперь получилось.